# Is there a R function that convert p.value to significance code?

Tags: r, p-value

`summary` displays significance code for p.values. Is there a R function that convert p.value to significance code? for example: 0.02 --> `'*'` and 0.005 --> `'**'`?

Comment: Try with `stars.pval(p.value)` from the `gtools` package

Comment: @ZheyuanLi something like `cut(x, breaks = c(0, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 1), include.lowest = T, labels = c('***', '**', '*', '.', ''))`?

Comment: Your answer is very neat, @mt1022, thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `symnum` as shown below. `?symnum` for more info.

```
p.values <- c(9.5e-15, 0.02)
Signif <- symnum(p.values, corr = FALSE, na = FALSE, cutpoints = c(0, 
    0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 1), symbols = c("***", "**", "*", ".", " "))
```

giving:

```
> str(Signif)
Class 'noquote'  atomic [1:2] *** *
  ..- attr(*, "legend")= chr "0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1"
```

The above code is used in R itself in `stats::printCoefmat` (see `?printCoefmat`) which is called from `stats:::print.summary.lm` .  Note that it produces an object of class `"noquote"` and also provides a legend in the `"legend"` attribute.

Answer (score 6):

Tracking down the code used by `summary`, you can find the following in [`stats:::printCoefmat`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/stats/R/anova.R#L150):

```
Signif <- symnum(pv, corr = FALSE, na = FALSE, 
                 cutpoints = c(0, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 1), 
                 symbols = c("***", "**", "*", ".", " "))
```

You can create your own function to do it, such as

```
signif.num <- function(x) {
    symnum(x, corr = FALSE, na = FALSE, legend = FALSE,
           cutpoints = c(0, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 1), 
           symbols = c("***", "**", "*", ".", " "))
}
signif.num(c(1e-8, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2))
```

(Note the last value is just a space and not visible in the output)